# Pytorch problems with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pytorch, pyinstaller, yolov5

After making the `.exe` file with `pyinstaller` I'm getting this error on launch:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 542, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 60, in __init__
  File "torch\hub.py", line 539, in load
    repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, trust_repo, "load",
  File "torch\hub.py", line 199, in _get_cache_or_reload
    sys.stderr.write('Using cache found in {}\n'.format(repo_dir))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Line 60 in main.py is:

```
self.model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
```

I was trying to change it to custom YOLO model (.pt file), change PyInstaller mode from windowed to console. Also, I upgraded PyInstaller from **5.11** to **5.12** (I found a scrappy thread on Korean forum)